# Customise Tinymce Fullscreen

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tinymce

I really like Wordpress' "Distraction free editing mode"

[image: Wordpress Fullscreen]

and don't like tinymce's default "fullscreen mode"

[image: Tinymce default Fullscreen]

Is there a plugin that I don't know of that is available for tinymce to allow for this?  By this I mean:

- spacing on the margins
- An outline that appears around content
- A toolbar that appears upon hover
- A save button that appears upon hover

Or, which I think is more likely, will I just have to style it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, because i am not much into wordpress, but their functionality is probably a tinymce plugin of their own. You could search for the tinymce plugin folder in a wordpress installation and copy the plugin you need from there.

Comment: You're right, there is a wpfullscreen plugin in the wordpress installation.  Location Path: wordpress/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpfullscreen.  I just have to figure out what the toolbar button is titled now!